# Excel VBA - Summing up different items

Tags: excel, vba, sum, items

Ppl

I have data like:

```
ID | Country
1  | DE
1  | GB
2  | DE
2  | DE
3  | GB
```

After using my macro, I have the following data:

```
1 | DE;GB
2 | DE
3 | GB
```

What I like to have, is:

```
1 | DE(1);GB(1)
2 | DE(2)
3 | GB(1)
```

I am not sure how my code is able to do the sums, could you help me with my request?

Attached my code:

```
Public Sub Calc()

Z = 2
z2 = 1

Do Until Cells(Z, 5).Value = ""


    If Cells(Z, 5).Value <> Kunde_Alt Then
        z2 = z2 + 1
        Cells(z2, 9).Value = Cells(Z, 5).Value
    End If

    s = 10
    Land = Cells(Z, 6).Value
    Gef = False
    Do Until Cells(z2, s).Value = ""

        If Cells(z2, s).Value = Land Then
            Gef = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        s = s + 1
    Loop

    If Gef = False Then
        Cells(z2, s).Value = Land
    End If


Kunde_Alt = Cells(Z, 5).Value
Z = Z + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you declare `Kunde_Alt` and `Land`? I assume `Land` is the country code? I'd add `Option Explicit` to the very very top, forcing you to declare all variables.  Also, I'd think you just need to add a counter to the loop where it sees how many country codes per ID you have, and add parenthesis around that.